# How to add another scale on the right part of y-axis in the same Python plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting some data in Python3 with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = list(range(0,10))
y = [ x*x for x in d]
plt.plot(d, y, c="r")
plt.ylabel("some unity")
plt.show()
```

where `y` and `d` are not the real data but were provided just to give a minimum working example.

What I would like to do is to put another scale and label on the right y-axis keeping the same graph.

So basically on the plot I have just one graph with one set of values in x and two set of values (two scales) in the y-axis one in the left and one in the right.

Is that possible?

NOTE: To make the question more clear, suppose I have the `x`, `y1` and `y2` lists of values where `y2` is a transformation of `y1`. Instead of doing `plot(x, y1)` and `plot(x, y2)` which would result in 2 different curves, I want to have one curve (for example from `plot(x,y1)` using `y1` as the left y-axis scale and `y2` as the right y-axis scale, (each one having its own unity-measurement/label).

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: In the example you posted it seems to be using a default scale. It is not clear there how to change it the second scale (for example passing another list).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. Both scales are automatically adjusted to the respective axes' content. Maybe you want to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Suppose I have the `x`, `y1` and `y2` lists of values where `y2` is a transformation of `y1`.
Instead of doing `plot(x, y1)` and `plot(x, y2)` which would result in 2 different curves, I want to have one curve (for example from `plot(x,y1)` using `y1` as the left y-axis scale and `y2` as the right y-axis scale.
That what I was asking in the question before it was put on hold.

Comment: For that you would of course need the transformation. I will replace the duplicate link.